# Apache Calcite transforming queries differently for same input query

Tags: query-optimization, apache-calcite

We are using Apache Calcite 1.30 version for building/transforming/optimise queries compatible to Redshift database. Calcite doing different transformations and each time new query getting hit on Redshift and redshift treat as new query instead serve from cache. Is there any way in calcite to create same query for same input raw query ?

Tried disabling calcite optimization step but didn’t help.